# How to append/update the objects in a JSON array to another JSON array inside an object

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

These are my two payloads.I want to add the second payload to first load using DataWave. Someone please help me. I want to add a second payload account to the first account without affecting the remaining data.

### payload 1

```
    [
    {
    "_id" : "7c2a355a-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
     "accounts" : [
       {
         //these are some accounts
         "account_id" : b206ae7e-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 123456,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 03501efa-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
        //second account
      {
         "account_id" : 416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 594154,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
      //third account
    {
         "account_id" : 416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 258963,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 65736c26-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
      "related entities" : [
       {
         "Entity_id" : 8a107a20-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
         "shortname" : "name"
          "addresses" : [
       {
        Entity_address_id : ca66ac66-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002
         city : XXX
        state : xxx
    }
    }
    ]
```

This is my first payload contains accounts and other information

### payload 2 :

```
    { 
        //first account
         "account_id" : 067094ce-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 464634,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 1c971994-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
        //second account
      {
         "account_id" : 24835d3e-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 14654163,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 03501efa-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    }
```

final Output :
//this is the final output by combining two payloads

```
    [
    {
    "_id" : "7c2a355a-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
     "accounts" : [
       {  
//first payload
         "account_id" : b206ae7e-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 123456,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 03501efa-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
        //second account
      {
         "account_id" : 416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 594154,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
    {
         "account_id" : 416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 258963,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 65736c26-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
    {
         "account_id" : 067094ce-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 464634,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 1c971994-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
      {
         "account_id" : 24835d3e-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
          account number : 14654163,
          current balance : {
           $number decimal : "0"
           },
           daily interest rate : null,
           collateral : [
        {
          "loan collateral id" : 03501efa-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
           "model" : car
    },
      "related entities" : [
       {
         "Entity_id" : 8a107a20-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002,
         "shortname" : "name"
          "addresses" : [
       {
        Entity_address_id : ca66ac66-1fcb-11ed-861d-0242ac120002
         city : XXX
        state : xxx
    }
    }
    ]
```

I am getting total 5 accounts in final payload.someone please help me to write the DataWeave code.

Comment: Please provide actual output and expected output. The formatting is making the question hard to read.

Comment: The second payload is an array? Note that none of the JSONs in the question are valid JSON. Please correct.

Comment: your input payloads are not correctly formatted, please use any online JSON formatter and fix it. for example jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the intention is to concatenate the accounts from payload1 and payload2, and that payload2 is actually an array, then you can just use the update operator. I'm showing a simplified example, which is what is recommended to do for this kind of questions since most of the payload information is not relevant to the answer.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var payload2=[ 
    { 
        "account_id" : "067094ce-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
        "account number" : 464634
    },
    { 
        "account_id" : "24835d3e-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
        "account number" : 14654163
    }    
]
---
payload[0]  update {
        case accounts at .accounts ->  accounts ++ payload2
}
```

Input payload:

```json
 [
    {
     "_id" : "7c2a355a-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
     "accounts" : [
       {
         "account_id" : "b206ae7e-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002", 
         "account number" : 123456
       },
       {
         "account_id" : "416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
         "account number" : 594154
       },
       {
         "account_id" : "416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
         "account number" : 258963
       }
    ]
   }
]
```

Output:

```json
{
  "_id": "7c2a355a-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "account_id": "b206ae7e-1fca-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
      "account number": 123456
    },
    {
      "account_id": "416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
      "account number": 594154
    },
    {
      "account_id": "416535ee-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
      "account number": 258963
    },
    {
      "account_id": "067094ce-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
      "account number": 464634
    },
    {
      "account_id": "24835d3e-1fcc-11ed-861d-0242ac120002",
      "account number": 14654163
    }
  ]
}
```